# ADODB to PDO quick switch

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, adodb

In past i use adodb for mysql in php. Now, i want to use PDO. Is there any way that for me to quick switch from adodb query to pdo using one connection to datebase?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the following two examples:

```
#PDO script:
$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=you_db_name;host=127.0.0.1", "root", "");
$rs = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($rs as $r) {}

#ADOdb script
require_once("adodb5/adodb.inc.php");
$ADODB_FETCH_MODE = ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC;
$db = NewADOConnection("mysql://root:@127.0.0.1/you_db_name");
$rs = $db->Execute("SELECT * FROM table");
foreach($rs as $r) {}
```

Note that PDO is a native compiled library and not loaded at runtime.

Comment: adodb5 can also run different modes - your sample is not necessarly PDO, eventhough it uses DNS connection.

Answer (score -2):

```php
<?php
class Config
{
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user =  "root";
    private $password =  "";
    private $dbname =  "php_crud";

    public function connect(){

        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
        $pdo =  new PDO($dsn,$this->user,$this->password);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $pdo;
    }
}
?>
```